# Server Configuration for Interactive Broker Client Portal API

Tags: api, interactive-brokers

I am looking for guide who have experience with Interactive Brokers Client Portal API. The Interactive Brokers CLient Portal API provides a gateway service.

I have tested this IB Gateway in my local and locally it is working fine.
The gateway is running on https://localhost:5000

I want to put this service on the windows server and want to access by server ip.
for example: https://52.xx.xx.12:5000 like this

I also tried solution from this reference [Running interactive brokers client portal API in cloud server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076621/running-interactive-brokers-client-portal-api-in-cloud-server) but not got success

Thanks

Comment: You can add interactive-brokers tag to reach more people

Comment: take a look at this video  which is awesome
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2F6PrPUG6w

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your server IP address in IB gateway setting as a trusted IP, and you should open 5000 port in firewall as well.